# How to retrieve the lost data

Tags: data-recovery

I was working on an excel file, and while closing it i clicked on don't save option and all the data got lost. Is there a way to retrieve the lost data

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify: You were working on an Excel file using which application? Check the timestamp on /tmp files around the time of your issue. One of those might have recoverable data.

Comment: Are you using Excel in Ubuntu Linux ?

Answer (score 3):

> i clicked on don't save option and all the data got lost

That is what "don't save" implies. Regardless what you are using closing with the "don't  save" option will not save anything to disk, and will remove any temporary file that was used to keep this cached.

> Is there a way to retrieve the lost data

No, nothing was saved to disk so there is nothing to restore from disk.